# When using a custom XML element in Android, I get a warning that the element is not allowed. How do I properly deal with it?

Tags: android, xml

Just so we're clear, the code works fine.

I'm a bit of a novice in Android development. The specific situation is that I have a preference screen in my Android app, and I have created a few custom preferences because the ones provided didn't completely satisfy my needs.

Let's say I have a preference screen like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="root">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="@bool/some_default_value"
        android:key="some_key"
        android:title="Some title" />

    <myPackageName.FoobarPreference
        android:defaultValue="Some default value"
        android:key="some_other_key"
        android:title="Configure foobars" />

    <myPackageName.EvilPreferenceOfDoom
        android:defaultValue="Some other default value"
        android:key="yet_another_key"
        android:title="Configure other foobars" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

where FoobarPreference and EvilPreferenceOfDoom are the custom preferences I created. The warnings say "Element myPackageName.FoobarPreference is not allowed here" and "Element myPackageName.EvilPreferenceOfDoom is not allowed here". Is there a way to properly deal with those warnings, or should I just suppress them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace **PreferenceScreen** with **android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen** in the root tag of your preference XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:key="root">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="1"
    android:key="some_key"
    android:title="Some title" />

<myPackageName.FoobarPreference
    android:defaultValue="Some default value"
    android:key="some_other_key"
    android:title="Configure foobars" />

<myPackageName.EvilPreferenceOfDoom
    android:defaultValue="Some other default value"
    android:key="yet_another_key"
    android:title="Configure other foobars" />

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```